# Prime factorization in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7})$

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a rational prime. I want to consider the factorization of $p$ in the pure cubic field $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/3})$.

I think the possible factorization is following.

(1)$p=p$ (i.e.,$p$ inert in $K$)

(2)$p=P_1P_2P_3$ (split completely)

(3)$p=P_1P_2$ (the residual degree of $P_1,P_2$ are $1,2$ respectively)

(4)$p=P_1P_2^2$($P_2$ is ramified)

(5)$p=P^3$ (ramified completely)

Can we determine the condition of $p$ when factorization is (1),(2),...,or (5)

Comment: Just look at how $f(X)=X^3-7$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Case (4) is impossible, case (5) only happens with $p=3,7$, case (3) iff $p\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ , and finally for $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, case (2) and (1) are decided by whether $7$ is a cubic residue mod $p$ or non CR.